# By-function in R

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to get familiar with the by-function in r. For some reasen I cannot get it to work properly. I try to count mean for every value for every sample plot.

I have following data:

```
       PuuID Sampleplot Value1 Value2 Value3
1      1          a      1      2      2
2      2          a      2      1      3
3      3          b      4      6      2
4      4          b      5      5      5
5      5          b      4      6      4
6      6          c      5      5      8
7      7          c      3      2      9
8      8          c      5      2      7
9      9          c      6      5      8
10    10          c      5      4      8
11    11          c      6      6      2
```

So far I have tried following:

```
data<-read.csv2("c:/data/data.csv", header = TRUE)
attach(data)
by(data[, 3:5], Sampleplot, mean)
```

and get following error:

```
Sampleplot: a
[1] NA
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Sampleplot: b
[1] NA
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Sampleplot: c
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the output from `str(data)` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a style issue it is better never to use `attach` but the real problem is that `colMeans` is needed here rather than `mean`:

```
> Sampleplot <- data$Sampleplot
> by(data[3:5], Sampleplot, colMeans)
Sampleplot: a
Value1 Value2 Value3 
   1.5    1.5    2.5 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Sampleplot: b
  Value1   Value2   Value3 
4.333333 5.666667 3.666667 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Sampleplot: c
Value1 Value2 Value3 
     5      4      7
```

or with `rbind`:

```
> do.call("rbind", by(data[3:5], Sampleplot, colMeans))
    Value1   Value2   Value3
a 1.500000 1.500000 2.500000
b 4.333333 5.666667 3.666667
c 5.000000 4.000000 7.000000
```

If you want to use `mean` then use `aggregate` like this:

```
> aggregate(data[3:5], data[2], mean)
  Sampleplot   Value1   Value2   Value3
1          a 1.500000 1.500000 2.500000
2          b 4.333333 5.666667 3.666667
3          c 5.000000 4.000000 7.000000
```

or `aggregate.formula`:

```
> aggregate(. ~ Sampleplot, data[2:5], mean)
  Sampleplot   Value1   Value2   Value3
1          a 1.500000 1.500000 2.500000
2          b 4.333333 5.666667 3.666667
3          c 5.000000 4.000000 7.000000
```

By the way, this is what was used for `data` (next time please use `dput` to output it in this form for reproducibility sake):

```
data <- structure(list(PuuID = 1:11, Sampleplot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"
), class = "factor"), Value1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 6L), Value2 = c(2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 6L), Value3 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 2L
)), .Names = c("PuuID", "Sampleplot", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers are being read in as factors. Use `stringsAsFactors=F` in your `read.csv2`. And use `as.numeric(data[,3:5])`. If you have *NA* in your data use `by(data[, 3:5], Sampleplot, mean,na.rm=T)`.

Alternatively, turn the columns into numeric columns first. `data[,3:5]=sapply(data[,3:5],function(x) { as.numeric(as.character(x)) } )`

Note: I changed the conversion of column type from `as.numeric` to `function(x) { as.numeric(as.character(x)) }` because not all of your factors seem to start from 1.